# Access Form - Mandatory First Field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking to set up my Access form so that the `Ref no.` field (which is mandatory) **must be completed first** before the user is allowed to progress to fill out the rest of the form.

By default the cursor is placed in the `Ref no` field but the user must not be allowed to navigate away before entering a value.

This is what I want to happen:

- User opens form
- Default field is `Ref no` where the user MUST enter a value before being allowed to move on to any other fields

Ideally the form will throw up an error message if the user navigates away from the `Ref no` field before they enter anything (the field cannot be blank).

Can this be done?

Comment: Again, WHY ? I think one of the basic rules of any "mouse driven environment" UI is that the user can click any control.

Comment: I have a reason which I will not be sharing with you due to confidentiality reasons; what I can say, however, is that the user(s) do (will) have total freedom within the form, but only once they have completed the reference number which is vital to my system and which must be entered first of all.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tab index of this field to 0. This is available through the properties of the field on the form. then use VBA, maybe something like this on the lost_focus command:

```
If IsNull(FieldName) Then
 MsgBox "Must provide value for FieldName"
 Cancel = True
End If
```

Comment: That's a clever solution. But it will also prevent the user to click any button in the form, I think.

Comment: ah maybe so, like a cancel or close form button perhaps? where the `lost_focus` as blank is necessary. I'll have a quick think and see if I can update my answer to be more thorough!

Comment: The index is already set to 0 and the VBA code is throwing me an error around the `Cancel` function.  I have updated my question to make it slightly clearer if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable all controls (except RefNo).
`AfterUpdate` of refNo, check for Null, Enable all controls, move to next control, then Disable RefNo so the user can't change/delete the entered value.
Anyway that sounds like a terrible idea. I'd rather rethink the process. Perhaps asking for the RefNo BEFORE entering that form. Never had to do that in 20 years.